# HTTP Status Code for Client being out of date

Tags: rest, http

I'm working on moving my REST API away from always responding with a `STATUS: 200 OK` containing an `error` key in the JSON returned if there was a problem, and trying to use the correct status codes in the event of problems.

So far I've moved most parts of my server over to the proper status codes `200, 201, 400, 401, 403, 404, 500, 501, and 503`

Currently I'm trying to figure out what the best way of rejecting the access to a API call for a client that is out of date. Currently I'm sending the version of the client encoded with the Authorization token.

I'm stuck between using status code `426, and 412`.  The title of the 426 status code seems like the use case I would want, but the description has me a little concerned.  `412` looks like it would be appropriate if i moved my versioning away from the authorization token and put it inside of it's own header.

This is my first REST API, and it works great, I'm just trying to convert it to following best practices. So I'm a little boggled.

TLDR;

- Should I move my versioning into Headers and use Status 412
- Should I use status code 426
- Is there a code I'm missing here I should be using to request the client to update.

NOTE: My client is not a web browser. It is a mobile device.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what you mean by "out of date?" It sounds like you want to notify clients with browsers too old to support certain features unrelated to HTTP.

Comment: @DaSourcerer At the bottom of my question I stated that my clients are a mobile device, when a client is "out of date" I mean the application version. So if an old app version requests data from `/v2/foo/ba` and it's stuck on `/v1` it should tell the client that it is out of date, and must update to access the resource on `/v2`

Comment: Thanks for the explenation, that wasn't entirely clear to me :)

Comment: Neither 412 nor 426 fit here - you really need to read & understand the error description; just looking at the default reason phrase is not sufficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let us walk through your proposed solutions real quick: Status code 412 is now under authority of [RFC 7232, section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2). It is to be used in the context of conditional requests if one or more preconditions described in [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3) of said RFC prevent the given request from being completed.

Code 426 is subject to [RFC 7231, section 6.5.15](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.15). This code lets the client know that the **[http] protocol version** used to access a resource is too old to complete the request. Both of these codes do not apply here.

With a bit of help from [this chart](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/), I think two codes were adequate here:

- **Code 400 / [Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)**

400 is a bit vague (and deliberately so), indicating a general issue with the request.

- **Code 403 / [Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)**

This is a bit of a stretch as this code is indicating an authorization issue. However, it is not inherently linked to *authentication*, so you should be fine here.

Personally, I would go with 400. You may also want to take a look at [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) for a standardized way of transmitting API errors.

Answer (score 1):

Hei Hobbyist...If you want to stick to official RFC release, then you should check the IETF site (Internet Engineering Task Force):

https://tools.ietf.org/html/

Not sure about which document, but for instance the HTTP/1.1 is part of RFC2616, but as I found in 2014 it was replaced by multiple RFCs (7230-7237).

The status 426 mentioned showed:

"
A server that sends a 426 (Upgrade Required) response MUST send an
Upgrade header field to indicate the acceptable protocols, in order
of descending preference.

A server MAY send an Upgrade header field in any other response to
advertise that it implements support for upgrading to the listed
protocols, in order of descending preference, when appropriate for a
future request.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.7 --> around page 57 you can find whole description :-)
"

Please have a look at those documents in order to decide which error code to give it back :-)

I hope this clarify your query. I wish you a nice day!

Comment: What's relevant is the status code registry, and that is located at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml

Comment: Very good link :-) To be precise the status codes are coming from RFC that is done by IETF, that is only a good overview on IANA.

Comment: To be really precise: the normative RFC about status codes (RFC 7231) delegates the registry function to IANA. So it's not an "overview" -- it really is the list of officially registered status codes.

Comment: @Marco, they are more than just an overview. The IANA registries are explicitly mentioned in the RFCs and have (in theory) authority over any of them. See also [RFC 7231, section 8.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-8.2)

Comment: Ok I see :-) Thanks a lot for the reference! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

It would be a 4xx status code, but I don't think there is one specific to your use case. Thus, 400 should do. (You can send error details in the body, see, for instance, https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7807.html)